# Multiple Google markers won't update position with drag listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events

Maybe I'm missing something here but I cannot seem to get the new position of my google marker after it has been dragged as it does not change. All seems to work with the first marker I set but any after that don't. I have a feeling it is pulling back the first Google markers data in the event listener even though I set a listener for each marker.

An example of my code is as follows:

```
for(let x=0; x<markerArr.length; x++) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: markerArr[x].lat,
                lng: markerArr[x].lng
            },
            map: map,
            title: markerArr[x].name,
            draggable: true,
            id: markerArr[x].id
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragstart', function() {
            console.log('Dragging start...');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag', function() {
           console.log('Dragging...');
           console.log(marker.getPosition().lat());
           console.log(marker.getPosition().lng());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend', function() {
            console.log("Drag ended: " + marker.getPosition());  
        });
}
```

Why would the listener only show the positions updating for the first marker in the markerArr? The other markers console log the same numbers which is the first markers position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `this` inside the callback function to refer to the marker.

At the end of the loop, `marker` is left pointing to the last marker created.

```
for(let x=0; x<markerArr.length; x++) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: markerArr[x].lat,
            lng: markerArr[x].lng
        },
        map: map,
        title: markerArr[x].name,
        draggable: true,
        id: markerArr[x].id
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragstart', function() {
        console.log('Dragging start...');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag', function() {
       console.log('Dragging...');
       console.log(this.getPosition().lat());
       console.log(this.getPosition().lng());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend', function() {
        console.log("Drag ended: " + this.getPosition());  
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jLpsvn3e/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
  var markerArr = [{lat:-34.397, lng: 150.644}, {lat: -34.497, lng: 150.644}]
  for(let x=0; x<markerArr.length; x++) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: markerArr[x].lat,
                lng: markerArr[x].lng
            },
            map: map,
            title: markerArr[x].name,
            draggable: true,
            id: markerArr[x].id
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragstart', function() {
            console.log('Dragging start...');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag', function() {
           console.log('Dragging...');
           console.log(this.getPosition().lat());
           console.log(this.getPosition().lng());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend', function() {
            console.log("Drag ended: " + this.getPosition());  
        });
}
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```